# Take out option from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to take out option value = 0 using JavaScript from below:

```
<select>
<option value=0>0</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
for (var i  = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].value === "0") {
        select.remove(i);
    }
}
```

See a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/SXQzD/). Annoyingly the value is a string so you have to `===` compare to the string. And getting the select by tagName assuming it's the only select on the page is prone to failure

using

`<select id="foo"> ... </select>`

and

`var select = document.getElementById("foo");`

Would be better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery:

```
$('select > option[value=0]').remove();
```

Obviously you should use the id of the select instead of `select` or you will hit all select items on that page.

Comment: @ThiefMaster there's no need to use jQuery for something this simple. At least there's no need to include jQuery for just this.

Comment: Sure, not just for that - but I doubt that's the only JS he's using.

Comment: It really depends. jQuery is only useful for fixing cross-browser issues and allowing for easy heavy DOM manipulation. If neither of those are neccesary then it's overkill and there are better alternatives.

Comment: what if that's the only javascript he uses on the entire site?

Comment: Why would he use JS to modify a form in that case? He could most likely edit the server-side code or the html file where the options are created.